# Problem getting jQuery .get (ajax) call to work

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, get

OK so I am going slightly insane. I am trying to do a simple thing that I have managed many times in the past, and that is to send data through jquery .get function via a simple onClick attribute.

I have checked that the jquery.js file is loading correctly through firebug's "net" panel, I have tried loading the jquery script from within the  tag and also just before the  tag; always using $(document).ready(function() { } wrapped round the script.

I just dont know what else to check to find the error.

The error is listed in firebug's console as **".... is not defined"**

Below you can find the code I am using, any help would be great; I am hoping I have simply been daft and missed a ; or something.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function productString(product) {
                $.get("http://<? echo ROOT; ?>includes/forms.php", { product: product }, function(data) {
                    //$('#popup-content').html(data);
                    alert('Load was performed.');
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" value="tester" onClick="productString(this.value)">
        <label>Test 1</label>
    </form>

    <a href="#" name="test" onClick="productString('tester2')">This is a test</a>

</body>
```

Thank you in advance for any help community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not working is that productString exists in the namespace defined by the anonymous function you pass to `$(document).ready`. When the browser acts on the onclick it is looking for the function in the global namespace and so doesn't find it. As the function does not rely on any of the DOM having been processed you do not need to wrap it in `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function productString(prod) {
        $.get("http://<? echo ROOT; ?>includes/forms.php", { product: prod }, function(data) {
            //$('#popup-content').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');
        });
    }
</script>
```

If `prod` is a string.

**Update**

Please note that I have made three changes.

1. calling jQuery CDN in a protocol less way cos i doubt whether **https** is your underlying protocol.
2. removed the `document.ready` wrapper as it makes no sense at all.
3. changed the function argument name from <strike>product</strike> to `prod`

Have you done all these?

Comment: Tried that but to no avail I am afraid. the error is stating that productString is not being defined, not sure if that helps further the investigation?

Comment: without using document.ready? and also note how the jquery cdn is called without protocol

Comment: @Daniel Wrigley You mean the function productString is not being defined? Try adding an alert before the $.get request to make sure the function is being called.